# Как сделать 1/3 места для flexbox?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы самый первый блок `.post__intro.first` занимал 2/3 места по горизонтали, а все блоки `.post__intro` занимали 1/3 места, как это сделать c помощью свойств флексбокса?
Блоку `.post__intro` я задал `flex: 1`, а `.post__intro.first` я задал `flex: 2`, но при таком решении при добавлении нового блока `.post__intro`, он не переходит на новую колонку

Пример, как должно выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1300px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.posts__intro {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post__intro {
 margin-top: 30px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: relative;
 flex: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.post__intro.first {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 flex: 2;
 margin-left: 0;
}

.post__intro:nth-child(3n+3) {
 margin-left: 0;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__content {
 position: absolute;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__title {
 font-size: 34px;
 line-height: 1.25;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__img {
 position: relative;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) img {
 box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 transition: filter .5s ease-in-out;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) img:hover {
 filter: grayscale(100%)
}

.post__intro.first  .post__intro__img:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-color: rgba(34, 41, 47, 0.9);
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__text {
 padding: 0 100px;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__info {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.post__intro__info span:not(:last-child)::after {
 content: '·';
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) .post__intro__title {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) .post__intro__info {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="posts__intro">

   <div class="post__intro first">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Zero BS CRM 3.0 Improves UI, Changes Database Structure, and Becomes More Extendable
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      The team behind Zero BS CRM launched version 3.0 of their WordPress plugin today. This is the first major release … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .first.post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

  </div> <!-- .posts__intro -->

 </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- .intro -->
```

Что происходит при добавлении новых блоков:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1300px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.posts__intro {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post__intro {
 margin-top: 30px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: relative;
 flex: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.post__intro.first {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 flex: 2;
 margin-left: 0;
}

.post__intro:nth-child(3n+3) {
 margin-left: 0;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__content {
 position: absolute;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__title {
 font-size: 34px;
 line-height: 1.25;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__img {
 position: relative;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) img {
 box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 transition: filter .5s ease-in-out;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) img:hover {
 filter: grayscale(100%)
}

.post__intro.first  .post__intro__img:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-color: rgba(34, 41, 47, 0.9);
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__text {
 padding: 0 100px;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__info {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.post__intro__info span:not(:last-child)::after {
 content: '·';
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) .post__intro__title {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) .post__intro__info {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="posts__intro">

   <div class="post__intro first">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Zero BS CRM 3.0 Improves UI, Changes Database Structure, and Becomes More Extendable
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      The team behind Zero BS CRM launched version 3.0 of their WordPress plugin today. This is the first major release … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .first.post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

  </div> <!-- .posts__intro -->

 </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- .intro -->
```

Comment: Вы уже это сделали задав `flex: 2` для `.post__intro.first`.

Comment: @E_K при добавлении новых блоков всё ломается, я добавил пример

Comment: Укажите минимальную ширину для блоков(min-width)

Comment: А почему не использовать псевдокласс :nth-child ? Судя по css вы умеете им пользоваться

Comment: Вас не смущает что блоки `.post__intro` вложены в `.post__intro`?
Сделайте для левой и правой части отдельные блоки обертки и уже обертке для левой части задайте `flex-grow: 2`.

Comment: @E_K `.post__intro` вложены в `.posts__intro`

Comment: Я использовал `min-width: 62.5%; max-width: 62.5%;` для первого элемента, для всех остальных `min-width: 30%; max-width: 30%;`, только это пришло в голову, но при сжатии первый элемент не равен двум частям остальных. Cклоняюсь к тому, что нужно изучить гриды, чтобы это нормально сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.posts {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.posts__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: calc((100% / 3) - 60px);
}
.posts__item:first-child {
  flex-basis: calc((100% / 3) * 2 - 50px);
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.posts__item:not(:nth-child(3)) {
  margin: 0 0 30px 30px;
}

.post {
  height: 300px;
}
.post img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="posts">
    <div class="post posts__item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" alt=""></div>
    <div class="post posts__item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" alt=""></div>
    <div class="post posts__item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" alt=""></div>
    <div class="post posts__item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" alt=""></div>
    <div class="post posts__item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```